# Python Numpy: Sub-arrays to one list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `x` that looks like this:

```
In: x
Out: 
array([[array([ 1.]), 0.0],
       [array([-0.00770808]), array([ 0.90825723])],
       [array([-0.0358526]), array([ 0.59267366])],
       [array([ 0.0088844]), array([ 0.89480382])],
       [array([ 0.0387529]), array([ 0.56483939])],
       [array([-0.08508252]), array([ 0.20664826])],
       [array([-0.04159874]), array([ 0.538443])],
       [array([ 0.07626737]), array([ 0.25998565])],
       [array([ 0.00222671]), array([ 0.97386301])],
       [array([-0.12652962]), array([ 0.0621885])],
       [array([ 0.01404373]), array([ 0.83703121])]], dtype=object)
```

You see that there are 11 tuples. I want to create a list with each of the first elements from each tuples. That would be a list that looks like this:
`[1, -0.00770808, -0.0358526, 0.0088844, 0.0387529 ... ]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> x[:,0].astype('float')
array([ 1.        , -0.00770808, -0.0358526 ,  0.0088844 ,  0.0387529 ,
       -0.08508252, -0.04159874,  0.07626737,  0.00222671, -0.12652962,
        0.01404373])
```

Comment: Ohhh I see ... astype('float')...that's what I was missing... I just need the `list` as well so `list(x[:,0].astype('float'))` Thanks!

Comment: @Plug4 You can use `x[:,0].astype('float').tolist()` if you need a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply issue

```
mylist = [a[0][0] for a in x]
```

where `x` is your array. Demo:

```
>>> mylist = [a[0][0] for a in x]
>>> mylist
[1.0, -0.00770808, -0.035852599999999998, 0.0088844000000000006, 0.0387529, -0.085082519999999995, -0.041598740000000002, 0.076267370000000001, 0.0022267099999999998, -0.12652962000000001, 0.014043730000000001]
```